# Why am I not receiving network signals on a Samsung S3 T-999?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, mobile-network, sim-unlocking

I just bought a Samsung S3 T-999. The problem is when I switch the cellphone on, it connects to my network but just for a second. The moment that second is gone, I lose signal completely.  So it's not like the IMEI is corrupted or something. Moreover, the phone is not asking for an unlock code at all, so I assume it is unlocked too.

What could possibly be the problem? How can I solve it?

This is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a really stupid thing. My phone's network mode was set to cdma while my country operates in gsm. It solved it.